# use boolean operator in jade conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, harp

I want to use a boolean operator in my jade template to activate the menu.
for that my syntax is like

```
li(class={ active: "blogs" or "post" == type })
  a(href='blog.html')
    | Blog
```

I am using harpjs to compile jade in to html templates, when I compiles the template it gives me error like,

```
  "name": "SyntaxError",
  "message": "Unexpected identifier",
```

How to add boolean conditions correctly in jade?

Comment: `or` isn't valid syntax, use `||`.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue with the help of [Ben Fortune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2615209/ben-fortune)'s Comment.

I replaced the `or` with `||` and the error was resolved.

the file code is looking like,

```
li(class={ active: "blogs" || "post" == type })
  a(href='blog.html')
    | Blog
```